# Make UICollectionViewCells with UIImageView height based on image

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to make a `UICollectionView` with the cells the width of the screen, but the height is based on the aspect ratio of the `UIImageView` inside.

In my current implementation all of the `UICollectionViewCell` instances are squares and this isn't what I want.

I want to use auto layout somehow to make the size of the image the width of the screen, but the relevant height depends on the aspect ratio of the image used.

Everything is done programatically in code.

[image]

My code:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.register(SubclassedCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 20, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 1)
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.view = collectionView
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? SubclassedCollectionViewCell {
            let data = self.data[indexPath.item]
            cell.setupCell(image: data)
            return cell
        }
        fatalError("Could not dequeue cell")
    }
}
```

with the cell

```swift
class SubclassedCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var hotelImageView: UIImageView = {
        var hotelView = UIImageView()
        hotelView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        hotelView.clipsToBounds = true
        return hotelView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(hotelImageView)
        hotelImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hotelImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        hotelImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        hotelImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        hotelImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupCell(image: String) {
        if let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: image) {
            hotelImageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the ratio based on the width and multiply by collection view width you can get a new height based on width.

Final Code: Remove itemSize from the loadview function. And calculate height and return item size in sizeForItemAt method.

loadView

```
override func loadView() {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 20, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 1) <-- Remove this
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.view = collectionView
}
```

UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? SubclassedCollectionViewCell {
            let data = self.data[indexPath.item]
            cell.setupCell(image: data)
            return cell
        }
        fatalError("Could not dequeue cell")
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        guard let iamgeData = UIImage(named: self.data[indexPath.item]) else {
            return .zero
        }
        let width = collectionView.bounds.width
        let heightOnWidthRatio = iamgeData.size.height / iamgeData.size.width
        let height = width * heightOnWidthRatio
        
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

[image]